# Monthly date reminder

Tags: php, date, events

Good day to all. I am creating a reminder that must each month, the 27th day do of the event to remind me. I do like this.

```
<? $date_today = date("d.m.y"); 
if ($date_today == "27.00.0000") {?> Burning! <? } ?>
```

But there is no effect. Please help me to solve the problem. Thanks to all! (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Debug your code. Check what the variable contains yourself. And compare that against the expected output yourself.

Comment: @PeeHaa... don't understand you.. please make an example

Comment: Why on earth do you think this will give you a month and year of `00` and `0000` to compare against? `$date_today = date("d"); 
if ($date_today == "27")`

Comment: @MarkBaker ... thank you, but not working(

Comment: Perhaps because today is the 28th?

Comment: @MarkBaker .. even if i change to 28.. nothing.. even if 27 or 30.. )

Comment: Which bit of "not working" [isn't it doing?](https://3v4l.org/bSQE4)

Comment: @MarkBaker i do like this <? $date_t = date("d"); if ($date_t == "28")  {?> Burning! <?}?> .. it's print Burning!, but if i change 28 to 27 or to other digits/days.. script continues to print Burning!

Comment: [Seems to work happily enough on 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/TXnX1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you should consider here:

1. Timezone
2. The day of month (not the month or year)

   ```
   date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

   $date_today = date("d");

   if ($date_today == 28) {
       echo "Burning";
   } else {
       echo "Fail";
   }
   ```

Output:

```
Burning
```

Comment: perfect but not work(.. even if i change timezone to EET, because i'm in Kiev (Eastern European Time).

Comment: working!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! i'm just add php after ?.... change <? to <?php and all working!... Mistic!